# Moquette internalPublish equivalent function in Apache ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: activemq-artemis

Is there an equivalent Moquette `internalPublish` function in Apache ActiveMQ Artemis? I need to publish some message from within the broker in my code. Could someone please tell me how this can be done in ActiveMQ Artemis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PostOffice.route(Message) methods.

The current implementation is taking PostOffice.route(ServerMessage message, direct). Pass false on direct otherwise the consumer will deliver within the same thread.

I wouldn't recommend that thought. The proper way would be to create a proper producer. Make it IN-VM if you like.

At the moment I am changing the signature to route(Message, boolean direct).